# What is a difference between dart:js and js package?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Everywhere in Dart documentation it is recommended to use `js` package for javascript interoperability.

However, I have recently found that `dart:js` package exists in SDK that seems to have similar (but not same) interface.

Are there any differences between these packages? Are they feature equivalent? Which one is recommended?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Js interop started with [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js). It was built with with [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Later [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) has been added to provide better performance and reduce the size of the compiled js file. Basically the goal were :

- removing scopes and lifecycle manual handling
- avoiding noSuchMethod to keep compilation size as low as possible
- renaming objects to make the api more understandable

Once *dart:js* has been ready, *package:js* has been rewrite to use *dart:js* under the cover.

*package:js* provides a simpler Api that comes at the cost of an increase of the js size (because *package:js* uses *dart:mirrors* and *noSuchMethod*).

Here is the same thing done with *package:js* and *dart:js* :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

main() {
  var pixi = new js.Proxy(js.context.PIXI.Stage, 0xffffff);
  var renderer = js.context.PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 400);
  document.body.append(renderer.view);
}
```

---

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  var pixi = new js.JsObject(js.context['PIXI']['Stage'], [0xffffff]);
  var renderer = js.context['PIXI'].callMethod('autoDetectRenderer', [400, 400]);
  document.body.append(renderer['view']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've received response regardless this on GitHub:

> That stack overflow comment is way out of date. Prefer `package:js` - we're working on updating docs to explicitly recommend that. It's no longer implemented over `window.postMessage` (that was a Dartium-based solution) - it's handled directly in the compilers and should be more efficient than `dart:js`.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35588#issuecomment-522097151