# js-interop: how to implement javascript `new` to dart with js-interop?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

javascript code is..

```dart
var terminal = new hterm.Terminal('nike');
```

I tried to use js-interop

```
var obj = js.context['hterm']['Terminal'];
var terminal = obj('nike');
```

but the result is wrong.   how to change `new` keyword from javascript to dart with js-interop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dart:js` :

```dart
var obj = js.context['hterm']['Terminal'];
var terminal = new js.JsObject(obj,['nike']);
```

Comment: Thanks! @Alexandre! by the way, what's difference between `package:js/js.dart` and `dart:js`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451731/what-is-a-difference-between-dartjs-and-js-package