# Using EasyRTC in dart: Class 'Proxy' has no instance getter 'iterator'

Tags: node.js, dart, dartium

As an experiment, I'm trying some stuff out with dart and easyrtc. I started at porting [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6kLSb/) (it is normally served through a nodejs server, found [here](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc/tree/master/server_example)) to a dart version and this is what I made from it

EDIT: I found out which part of the code is causing the error. It is the data object proxy which the for loop is unable to run through. Normally, the setRoomOccupantListener function gives as parameters the name of the room and an object with all the peers connected to the room. I have made a screenshot of the object layout in normal javascript as how it looks when I debug in chrome, found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWFiE.png).

```
function connect() {
  easyrtc.setRoomOccupantListener(convertListToButtons);
 }

function convertListToButtons (roomName, data, isPrimary) {
  clearConnectList();
  var otherClientDiv = document.getElementById("otherClients");
  for(var easyrtcid in data) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.onclick = function(easyrtcid) {
      return function() {
        performCall(easyrtcid);
      };
    }(easyrtcid);

    var label = document.createTextNode(easyrtc.idToName(easyrtcid));
    button.appendChild(label);
    otherClientDiv.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/addXN.jpg) is the screenshot when i debug the dart code in chromium

```
void connect() {
  easyrtc.setRoomOccupantListener(convertListToButtons);
  } 

void convertListToButtons(roomName, data, isPrimary) {
  clearConnectList();
  var otherClientDiv = querySelector("#otherClients");
  for (var easyrtcid in data) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.onClick.listen((event) {
      performCall(easyrtcid);
    });

    button.appendText(easyrtc.idToName(easyrtcid));
    otherClientDiv.append(button);
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Class 'Proxy' has no instance getter 'iterator'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'iterator' Receiver: Instance of 'Proxy' Arguments: []
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      P...<omitted>...7)
```

Am I missing something simple here or is this some kind of incompatibility? Thank you.

Comment: Please use dart:js instead of package:js

Comment: following https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js, there is no difference between the two other then performance and syntax, so why should I switch if I dont give that much about performance?

Comment: Code size and the fact that we're probably going to discontinue package:js as it is now in favor of a code-generation approach. When packages:js is used together with any other library that uses mirrors, very bad things happen.

Comment: That's bad, and I actually dislike the way dart:js works. the callmMethod with it's parameters results in just gorgeous code

Comment: It's worse that package:js can severely bloat dart2js output, when all it gives is slightly nicer syntax. It's not worth it.

Comment: More than slightly in my opinion, are there any plans on improving the syntax later on?

Answer (score 1):

**I see you can use `import package:js/js.dart';` too. I don't know how to use it**

You could try

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/

This looks weird too

```dart
easyrtc = js.context.easyrtc; // <== here you have context 'easyrtc'

easyrtc.easyApp('easyrtc.audioVideo', 'selfVideo', new js.JsObject.jsify(['callerVideo']), loginSuccess, loginFailure); 
// and here again 'easyrtc.audioVideo', I guess this is one to much
```

try

```dart
easyrtc.easyApp.callMethod('audioVideo', ['selfVideo', js.JsObject.jsify(['callerVideo']), loginSuccess, loginFailure]);
```

where 'audioVideo' is the called method and the rest are arguments

```dart
easyrtc.callMethod('easyApp', ['audioVideo', 'selfVideo', js.JsObject.jsify(['callerVideo']), loginSuccess, loginFailure]);
```

where 'easyApp' is the called method and the rest are arguments.

If you can add how the code would look in JavaScript I could create better examples.

Comment: in the first sentence there is a link pointing to a jsfiddle page with  the javascript in it. Because there it is not served through nodejs it will not work though

Answer (score 1):

Like `dart:js` [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) doesn't handle directly Dart List. So the following line :

```dart
  easyrtc.easyApp('easyrtc.audioVideo', 'selfVideo', 
      ['callerVideo'], loginSuccess, loginFailure);
```

should be :

```dart
  easyrtc.easyApp('easyrtc.audioVideo', 'selfVideo', 
      js.array(['callerVideo']), loginSuccess, loginFailure);
```

See also [What is a difference between dart:js and js package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451731/what-is-a-difference-between-dartjs-and-js-package)